# Swift how to move tableView backGroundView label

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7

I have a tableView that has :

1-) Section 1 header

```
    TableView Cell
```

2-) Section 2 header

```
    Tableview Cell
```

3-) Section 3

```
    (n rows that contains list of records)
```

My tableView has 3 section. In section 3 i'm listing records. When there is no record i'm show a label that says "No Records Found" my table view like the picture below.

[My Table View Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e885u.png)

But my issue is , i want to move the label to bottom of the tableview(on the " + " view) How can i move this label. This is my swift code

```
func setNoDataInfoIfAbsenceNotExists()
{
    let noDataLabel : UILabel = UILabel()
    noDataLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 , (self.tableView.bounds.width), (self.tableView.bounds.height))
    noDataLabel.text = "No Records Found"
    noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    noDataLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    self.tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .None
}
```

Comment: why don't you use storyboard instead and change the constraint ???

Comment: What do you mean by on the " + " view? Do you mean to make label subview of + view or on tap of + you want to move the label???

Comment: nodataLabel.frame = (+View).frame try this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line

```
tableView.tableFooterView  = tableViewFooter
```

you got result like this. See view in blue color in bottom of textview
.

your view just stick to your tableview height and you got your view in the end of the tableview always.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're making frame `noDataLabel` to be size of table view and text is center in this frame.

You should try making frame smaller (try CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) and after setting text call `noDataLabel.sizeToFit()`), then position it using `noDataLabel.center.x` and `noDataLabel.center.y`.

Try:

```
noDataLabel.text = "No Records Found"
noDataLabel.sizeToFit()
noDataLabel.center.x = tableView.center.x
noDataLabel.center.y = tableView.frame.height - noDataLabel.frame.height
```

Comment: noDataLabel.text = "No Records Found"
        noDataLabel.sizeToFit()
        noDataLabel.center.x = tableView.center.x
        noDataLabel.center.y = tableView.frame.height -noDataLabel.frame.height  i add this lines but label is still on same location

Comment: Have you tried: noDataLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 , 0, 0)?

Comment: let noDataLabel : UILabel = UILabel()
noDataLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0 , 0,0)
noDataLabel.text = "No Records Found"
noDataLabel.sizeToFit()
noDataLabel.center.x = tableView.center.x
noDataLabel.center.y = tableView.frame.height - noDataLabel.frame.height    yes i tried

Comment: Just to be sure, can you add (anywhere in that function): dump(tableView.frame) and check if the frame size of tableView is correct?

Comment: ▿ (0.0, 72.0, 414.0, 616.0)
  ▿ origin: (0.0, 72.0)
    - x: 0.0
    - y: 72.0
  ▿ size: (414.0, 616.0)
    - width: 414.0
    - height: 616.0 this is the dump result

Comment: Ah, remove the: self.tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel and replace it with tableView.backgroundView!.addSubview(noDataLabel) - there must be a backgroundView, otherwise you can add new view as background view (with frame of tableView) and add to it the label. Let me know if that works (noDataLabel can be obscured by other views though).

Answer (score 0):

Create new cell which will contain label with text "No Results" (or whatever do you need).
In your code:

inside `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
//other part of your implementation
if indexPath.section == 3 {
    return dataArray.isEmpty ? 1 : dataArray.count
}
```

inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
// other part of your implementation
if indexPath.section == 3 {
    guard !dataArray.isEmpty else {
        return NoDataCell() // replace with your implementation
    }         return YourDataCell()
}
```

Comment: But in this case "no data cell" will be selectable and behave like a cell. I think use the cell as a footer is a better idea. Isnt it?